# Forklifts stop moving and freeze in place

Tags: anylogic

I am facing an interesting problem with this warehouse model of mine. I have forklifts that move shipments around a network- the warehouse, and the model seems to be running fine until st some point forklifts start getting stuck at random location in the network for no reason. The longer I run the model the more forklifts are stuck. The are like completely frozen in place. At first I was defining the number of forklifts- resource pool capacity, using a schedule and I thought that might be the problem, so I went a head and changed it to constant capacity, and the problem still arises as you can see in this image.
[image: Forklifts stuck in the network]

As far the resource pool, the seize, and release blocks concerned; I kept the default settings and didn't change anything.

Here's a screenshot of the resource pool properties. I defined forklift as an agent and inside that agent is nothing but the image of a forklift and at the "use in flowchart as" box I set it to resource unit. I don't quite understand the 100 at the end of shift priority box, but I left it at the default value.
[image: Resource pool properties]

Here's a screenshot of one of seize blocks but all the block are similar

[image]

Similarly, this is screenshot of one of release blocks where the forklifts return to their home location after each task. Here I tried all the options from return to home every time to release from a given pool and choose the forklift pool or just releases the correspondent seize block, and that all didn't resolve the issue

[image]

Again, the model runs fine and only after 10% of the running time period this starts to happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well-defined question, thx for the effort :) . Why do you not use the Material-handling libraries and make your forklifts into transporters? They are much better at finding paths... Try that and see if it solves the problem.